# How to go back 5 secs back while playing in Titanium, on button click this should happen

Tags: ios, audio, titanium, playback, duration

I have the following code.

```
var file = recording.stop(); 
sound = Titanium.Media.createSound({sound:file});

sound.play();

sound.getTime(); // This will return the current time position of the audio.

var goBack = Titanium.UI.createButton({title:'Go Back',height:40,width:200,top:230});
goBack.addEventListener('click',function(){
      if(sound.playing){
        Ti.API.info(sound.getTime()); // If this prints 25 secs.
       }
});
win.add(goBack);
```

Assuming that currect `getTime()` returns 25 and i need to play the audio from 20 secs on button click.

How do i do this?

I can use something like this

```
setTime = sound.getTime() - 5
```

But How do we pass the float value to sound.setTime?

And also Is there any way to add seek bar to indicate the play status of the sound object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the time value like this:

```
sound.time = 20.0; // assuming that you want to start the sound from 20th second.
```

You can add a progress bar like this:

```
     var pb = Titanium.UI.createProgressBar({
            min:0,
            value:0,
            width:200
      });

     //when you play the sound set
     pb.max = sound.duration;

    // when your sound is complete

    sound.addEventListener('complete', function()
    {
        pb.value = 0;
    });

    // and also add this code to your file

    //INTERVAL TO UPDATE PB


    var i = setInterval(function()
    {
        if (sound.isPlaying())
        {
            Ti.API.info('time ' + sound.time);
            pb.value = sound.time;

        }
    },500);


    //  CLOSE EVENT - CANCEL INTERVAL
    win.addEventListener('close', function()
    {
        clearInterval(i);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Muhammad, It worked like a charm.

But I need to know the difference between
sound.time = 20;

and

var newTime = sound.getTime() - 5.0;

sounnd.setTime(newTime);

Comment: I also tried to set the volume(in my case) when i was working on sound player, but it didn't work for me. Then i used the properties of the sound player. setTime(), getTime() are the methods but didn't work in my condition.